# Error: "cannot assign to immutable expression of type UITableViewCel.type"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm getting an error:

> Cannot assign to immutable expression of type `UITableViewCel.type`

I'm trying to make a to-do list app. How do I fix this error?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   Error -> ** var cell = UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell**
    if  cell {
        cell = UITableView(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    cell.textLable.text = "Hi"
    return cell
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two assignment statements in one line for one variable.

Instead, use:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Hi" //check spelling of textLable?
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

You don't need to cast cell as UITableViewCell as the function dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier already returns a UITableViewCell by default.

Answer (score 0):

You error comes from the fact that you are trying to assign `UITableViewCell` to `cell`.

```
var cell = UITableViewCell = ...
```

And to dequeue a cell you should use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:forIndexPath:)` as it returns a non optional cell.